# Joomla Administrator Panel login issue

Tags: joomla2.5

I have a site in Joomla
http://kvmshop.kr.cisinlive.com/administrator/index.php . I am trying to login in admin area but I am not able to login. It always redirects me to the same page without any error i.e http://kvmshop.kr.cisinlive.com/administrator/index.php .
I read in some forums that this issue occurs due to whitespaces in configuration file. I removed whitespaces too from configuration file. 
I set 644 permission for configuration files.

Please help me with this issue. I am fed up with this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access your database tables with something like PHPMyAdmin? The first that comes to mind is that there is something in there set to "0" (or, unpublished).

If you can access your tables, go to the `jos_plugins` table and search for a value called `User - Joomla` and for another value called `Authentication – Joomla`, if those are set to `0` then that is the issue, set that to `1` and click "Go" or "Save".

That should fix the login issue.

Comment: thanks for reply.. I found some one has hacked my define.php file in includes folder and added encoded hacking code. My issues is solved